# Elastic Search: Use Query or Filtered Query for term, prefix or range queries?

Tags: caching, elasticsearch, scoring

I wonder if I should translate my Term Queries into a filtered Query to cache the results and to keep the score?

From the documentation of [filtered query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html):

> Filters are usually faster than queries because:
>
> - they don’t have to calculate the relevance _score for each document — 
>     the answer is just a boolean “Yes, the document matches the filter” or
>     “No, the document does not match the filter”.
> - the results from most
>     filters can be cached in memory, making subsequent executions faster

Also, from the [filters](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html):

> Some filters already produce a result that is easily cacheable, and
>   the difference between caching and not caching them is the act of
>   placing the result in the cache or not. These filters, which include
>   the term, terms, prefix, and range filters, are by default cached and
>   are recommended to use (compared to the equivalent query version) when
>   the same filter (same parameters) will be used across multiple
>   different queries (for example, a range filter with age higher than
>   10).

My solution is that I would then put the term query inside a filtered query, where the "query" and "filter" predicate are the same.
I guess that I then have the best of both worlds, scoring and caching. Does this makes sense?

Sample Query:

```
{
  "_source":true,
  "query":{"term":{"displayName":"example name"}}
}
```

Optimized Filtered Query:

```
{
  "_source":true,
  "query":
  {"filtered":
   {"query":{"term":{"displayName":"example name"}},
    "filter":{"term":{"displayName":"example name"}}
   }
  }
}
```

I have tested this, but didn't noticed some performance gains. As I have to write a lot of search terms beforehand, I would like to know what is the best solution and why.